# Formik not displaying errors in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I am trying to get the validation errors to display on touch but for some reason they're not showing up. I've tried following the tutorial on the official Formik website, but to no avail. I am using React-Bootstrap, Formik, and Yup for validation. What am I doing wrong?

**Imports:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
```

**Validation Schema:**

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  companyName: yup
    .string()
    .required('Company Name is required')
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 characters allowed')
    .max(100, 'Maximum 100 characters allowed'),
});
```

**Form:**

```
<Formik
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    initialValues={{
        companyName: '',
    }}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
>
    {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form autoComplete='off'>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>
                    Company Name <span className='text-danger'>(*)</span>
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type='text' name='companyName' placeholder='Enter Company Name' />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>{errors.companyName}</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: `{errors.companyName` -> `{errors.companyName}`

Comment: That's a typo, I do have the correct `{errors.companyName}`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your input fields are not connected to the `Formik`.
You could use the `Field` from Formik to wire your inputs to Formik.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  companyName: yup
    .string()
    .required('Company Name is required')
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 characters allowed')
    .max(100, 'Maximum 100 characters allowed'),
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    initialValues={{
        companyName: '',
    }}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
>
    {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form autoComplete='off'>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>
                    Company Name <span className='text-danger'>(*)</span>
                </Form.Label>
                <Field type='text' placeholder='Enter Company Name' name="companyName" />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>{errors.companyName}</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
  );
}
```